# Is Linked MDB up-to-date?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, linked-data, linkedmdb

When I try to look for [*The Machine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110425) and many other films in LinkedMDB, I'm not able to find them.  I can get the film's IMDB URL and query for the foaf:page property with the SPARQL endpoint, using a query like this, but it returns no results.

```
prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select * where{
    ?film foaf:page ?imdb;
    dcterms:title ?title
    filter regex(str(?imdb), "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110425", "i")
}
```

As you can see, the query contains a regex in order to catch the matching resource. Are there some errors in my query or does the LinkedMDB repository not contain all the IMDB's films (the film that I'm looking for is very old)?

Comment: Did you find anything on their page (documentation, etc.) that suggests that they *are* up to date?  On their statistics page, there's a note that there are 541,810 `foaf:page` links with IMDb, Rotten Tomatoes and Freebase.com pages.  I bet that means that there are movies not in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything on the LinkedMDB site that suggest that they have information about all the films that IMDB knows about.  The following query on their endpoint doesn't return any results, so I think that the movie you're looking for isn't listed there.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
 { ?resource rdfs:label "La Machine" } union
 { ?resource rdfs:label "The Machine" } union
 { ?resource dc:title "La Machine" } union
 { ?resource dc:title "The Machine" }
}
```

Also, your original query is more complicated than it needs to be.  Regular expression matching can be expensive, and if you already have a URI, then you should just ask about it, with a query like:

```
select * where{
  ?film foaf:page <http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110425> ;
        dcterms:title ?title .
}
```

Comment: As always thank you  for you answer and your tips.
I've not found any details about that so I've asked here. Apparently, seems that Linked MDB is not really up-to-date and I can deduce it from its sparql endpoint (snorql).
Do you have any experience with this repository?

Comment: Sure, browse the [tag:linkedmbd] questions. :)  If this worked for you, do consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  If it didn't, though, what can be improved here?